# How to split a file containing a speech into a list of words on python 3?

Tags: split, python-3.6

My assignment is to take in State of the Union addresses by President Bush and President Obama and to figure out the number of unique words (or vocabulary size) and the top 20 most frequently used words. I am on the first stage of counting the number of unique words and have this so far:

```
    def uniqueWords(fileName):
fileIn = open(fileName, 'rt', encoding = 'UTF-8')
fileS = open('stopwords.txt', 'rt', encoding = 'UTF-8')
stop = fileS.split()
words = fileIn.split()
for x in range(len(words)):
    words[x] = words[x].lower()
    for z in words[x]:
        if z in '~!@#$%^&*()+=_:;,./\?"{}[]<>|':
            words[x] = words[x].replace(z, '')

unique_words = 0
while unique_words < len(words):
    if words[i] in stop:
        words.remove(words[i])
    else:
        unique_words += 1
return unique_words
```

I keep getting the following error:

> > > uniqueWords('bush_all.txt')
> > >               Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >                  File "", line 1, in 
> > >                   uniqueWords('bush_all.txt')
> > >                 File "/Users/sarahloughran/Documents/CSCI 203/final                   project/countWords.py", line 12, in uniqueWords
> > >           stop = fileS.split()
> > >       AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'

Everywhere that I have looked has told me to use the file.split() function so I'm not sure why this error is occurring. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read a file, you first have to go through all the lines before you can split the lines into idividual words. You can use listcomprehension like this

```
stop = [word for line in fileS.readlines() for word in line.split()]
words = [word for line in fileIn.readlines() for word in line.split()]
```

The rest of the code looks fine.